# designer.cs not showing in solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 and need to view the designer.cs file for one of my webforms.  However, when I expand the aspx file in the solution explorer, it does not show up.  How do I force Visual Studio to show me the designer.cs file?

Here's what I see in Solution Explorer:

[image]

Also, I seem unable to edit the project file (.csproj) by hand so that it will show the designer.cs file because I can't find the project file in the folder containing the code.  Here's a screenshot of that folder:

[Folder Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMrDi.png)

Comment: What happens when you right-click the form and choose "View Code"?

Comment: It takes me to the code behind file

Comment: Is this behavior happening for all your web forms or just one?  If you add a brand new web form to the project, does that one show both the .cs and the designer.cs files?  If so, check the designer.cs file and make sure that at the top it says: `public partial class About` and that the class name matches the class in the .cs file. It's important that the `partial` keyword is there in the designer.cs file (it should not be in the .cs file).

Comment: It happens for all my webforms.  I just added a brand new one, and it happened to that one, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Dave in the comments above - It appears that your project is configured as a web site instead of a web application. I would recommend that you convert your project to a web application by creating a new project and re-adding the files. You can read up on the differences between the two models here on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In order for a designer file to show up beneath a source code file within the Project Explorer, the project file (**.csproj**) must have an entry as follows:

```
<Compile Include="page.aspx.cs">
  <DependentUpon>page.aspx</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="page.aspx.designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>page.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Please open your ProjectName.csproj file and check to see that this pattern exists for your source file (.cs) and designer source file (.designer.cs).

You will have to unload and then reload your project from Visual Studio for changes to the Project File to take effect.

Comment: I'm hesitant to edit the project file by hand.  Is there a configuration setting in Visual Studio that will do this?

Comment: The project file is merely an XML file telling Visual Studio how to organize files.  Do not be intimidated by it :).  I would recommend at the least opening it up and seeing if something got goofed up with respect to the above pattern I have posted.  If you are apprehensive about messing something up, make a copy of the solution folder and view/edit the copy to see if it resolves your problem.

Comment: Another approach could be to "exclude" the page.aspx file from within the project explorer and then re-add it to the solution.  I've seen problems like this occur when multiple files are added at the same time, rather than one-by-one (sometimes the .designer.cs files don't get associated as they should).  Hope all this helps!

Comment: Hmmm... I can't seem to find the .csproj file.  I edited the original question, adding a screenshot of what's in the directory with my code.

Comment: It appears that your project is configured as a *web site* instead of a *web application*.  I would recommend that you convert your project to a *web application* by creating a new project and re-adding the files.  You can read up on the differences between the two models [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx).

Comment: Additionally, in your screenshot of folder contents, I do not see a "Container.aspx.designer.cs" file.  Perhaps your solution is configured properly but the file is missing?

Comment: The problem was that it was a web site... if you want to edit your answer I'll mark it as the solution.