# Why is *.designer.vb and *.resx not being added dependent when adding as link in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

This is in my project when I add as a link a form into VS2015.

```xml
<Compile Include="..\..\..\..\..\ProductionLibs\ProductionLibs\FYIReports\frmFYIReport.designer.vb">
  <Link>NewFolder1\frmFYIReport.designer.vb</Link>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="..\..\..\..\..\ProductionLibs\ProductionLibs\FYIReports\frmFYIReport.vb">
  <Link>NewFolder1\frmFYIReport.vb</Link>
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Same formed that was linked in VS2010.

```xml
<Compile Include="..\..\..\..\ProductionLibs\ProductionLibs\FYIReports\frmFYIReport.designer.vb">
  <Link>FYIReporting\frmFYIReport.designer.vb</Link>
  <DependentUpon>frmFYIReport.vb</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="..\..\..\..\ProductionLibs\ProductionLibs\FYIReports\frmFYIReport.vb">
  <Link>FYIReporting\frmFYIReport.vb</Link>
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Notice the missing `<DependentUpon>`.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961449/designer-cs-not-showing-in-solution) got me in the right area, my question is why is 2015 not working? This is happening on every form. I am use VB not C#. Although I am missing the `<DependentUpon>` attribute, we are not getting there the same way. If I open the 2010 project in 2015, all is good. Then if I remove the link and re-add it, I am broke. Not sure if I made a mistake, but when I tried to hack the project file and add the `<DependentUpon>`, it still did not work. I can repeat this over and over. I am seeing the same issue with the *.resx file.

Comment: @GSerg, thanks for fixing it, just curious what did I do wrong? I hate making the same mistake twice. :-)

Comment: Started the project over in VS2010. Added all the link forms, then opened it in VS2015. All works as expected. One thing I learned the hard way, when it is messed up, and you change something in the designer and save. You just lost any controls that was on the screen. This form we have been using for years, glad there was a backup. :-)

Comment: You did not [put `\``s](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) around the `<DependentUpon>` so [it was removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/147640).

Comment: So I violated a markdown rule. What was strange, I don't remember it show it in the wysiwyg. Thanks, I am still learning etiquette.

Comment: It's not about etiquette, it's just that it was not visible to your readers what you were talking about because all instances of `<DependentUpon>` did not display. It does not display in the wesiwyg either. You can [compare](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41386761/revisions) the before and the after.